# Is there any easy way to implement multicast DNS using javascript and browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, multicast, service-discovery, mdns

Is there any easy way to implement multicast DNS using javascript and browser?

I'm seeing zeroconf /polo which depends on node.js, but I'm looking for the solution for multicast DNS/ Service discovery like zeroconf/polo which will work on browsers(at least chrome and firefox).